# Using a string to reference a variable in C++

Tags: c++

Is it even possible to use a string to reference a variable in c++? Note that this is a wrapper around a c project.

I have an incoming message that looks like with data populated in all 3 variables:

```
struct {
  char[20] var_a;
  char[20] var_b;
  char[20] var_c;
} data_type;
```

Additionally, I have another incoming message that can either be a string of "var_a", "var_b", or "var_c"

Is there anyway I can extract the data based on my incoming message.

For example

```
char new[20] = str2var("var_a")
```

Where str2var is just there to represent what I am trying to do. The size of the message and the data are already defined, I just need the ability to select which data to pull out based on another function.

Any other ideas to accomplish this goal are welcomed.

Comment: `str2var` would have to take another object, would it not?

Comment: whatever solution you get is likely to involve a `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use an `if else` chain and `strcmp`?

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, you should be able to index the last character, and just use a case statement.

```
char[20] m2;  // second message

switch (m2[4]) {

  case 'a':
    // use var_a
    break;

  case 'b':
    // use var_b
    break;

  case 'c':
    // use var_c
    break;

  default:
    // error
    break;
}
```